# How do I break an unordered list in the middle?

Tags: css, html-lists

If I have a list like

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

How could I get it to display horizontally for say the first two items and the next three, but break into a second row between them?

Edit: looking for a CSS solution, so I can select whether to do this based on viewport size.

Comment: Make your <li> `display: inline`, and add a `<br />` where you want a break. If you want elements next to each other horizontally, make them `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darienh/ukcgu8aL/)

Comment: not sure what you mean. like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vbexao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Flexbox(css) you can achieve this. With this solution it depends on how many elements to show on the first row. For example if you want for elements to show on the first row you divide 100 by 4 which gives 25 and give the width 25%;
Below are three samples. I hope this helps

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
li {
  width: 33.33%;
}

ul+ul{
  width: 100px;
}
ul+ul li {
  width: 50%;

}
ul+ul li:nth-last-of-type(-n+3) {
  width: 33.33%;
}

ul + ul + ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 150px;
}
ul + ul + ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 50%
}
ul + ul + ul li {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `column-count: 2;` on the `ul` to create two columns into which the list will be evenly distributed:

```css
ul {
column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a table. Use row span and col-span to help with you alignment

Comment: Use OP's code to provide the code needed for this solution please.